# Moving from file logging to database logging

Tags: logging, nosql

We are currently considering moving from logging to files, to logging to a NoSQL database.  Another team in our company is starting to use HBase but that looked quite complex for what we would like to do.  I have been looking at MongoDB but i would like some suggestions.

Currently we have hundreds of servers in farms for different applications.  Whenever we hear of a problem from one of the applications there is a long process the retrieve the logs from app ops and then a long process to sift through them all to find the problem.  We are looking at just moving all of our logging into a central place and building a web UI around it so we can access and query the logs more easily.

Which NoSQL database would be a good fit for storing and querying applications log?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've seen a lot of companies are using **MongoDB** to store application logs. Its schema-freeness is really flexible for application logs, at which schema tends to change time-to-time. Also, its [Capped Collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/) feature is really useful because it automatically purges old data to keep the data fit into the memory.

People aggregates the logs by normal Grouping or MapReduce, but it's not that fast. Especially MongoDB's MapReduce only works within a single thread and its JavaScript execution overhead is huge. [New aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) could solve this problem.

When you use MongoDB for logging, the concern is the **lock contention** by high write throughputs. Although MongoDB's insert is fire-and-forget style by default, calling a lot of insert() causes a heavy write lock contention. This could affect the application performance, and prevent the readers to aggregate / filter the stored logs.

One solution might be using the **log collector framework** such as [Fluentd](http://fluentd.org/), [Logstash](http://logstash.net/), or [Flume](http://flume.apache.org/). These daemons are supposed to be launched at every application nodes, and takes the logs from app processes.

They buffer the logs and **asynchronously** writes out the data to other systems like MongoDB / PostgreSQL / etc. The write is done by **batches**, so it's a lot more efficient than writing directly from apps. This link describes how to put the logs into Fluentd from PHP program.

- [Fluentd: Data Import from PHP Applications](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/php)

Here's some tutorials about MongoDB + Fluentd.

- [Fluentd + MongoDB: The Easiest Way to Log Your Data Effectively](http://blog.10gen.com/post/27619817959/fluentd-mongodb-the-easiest-way-to-log-your-data) on 10gen blog
- [Fluentd: Store Apache Logs into MongoDB](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/apache-to-mongodb)

MongoDB's problem is it starts slowing down when the data volume exceeds the memory size. At that point, you can switch to other solutions like **Apache Hadoop** or **Cassandra**. If you have a distributed logging layer mentioned above, you can switch to another solution as you grow. This tutorial describes how to store logs to HDFS by using Fluentd.

- [Fluentd: Fluentd + HDFS: Instant Big Data Collection](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/http-to-hdfs)

Answer (score 1):

Late response but this case looks like a great fit for:

> Logstash: The server component of Logstash that processes incoming logs
>
> Elasticsearch: Stores all of the logs
>
> Kibana: Web interface for searching and visualizing logs

You can use Logstash Forwarder to send logs to Logstash. It serves as a log forwarding agent. You can watch for log files of various formats, databases and message stores and pump them up to the Elasticsearch DB.
After that you use Kibana web ui to watch everything. Do not build custom solution using SQL/NoSQL database for this purpose.

> Splunk is another commercial solution doing it in similar
> architecture.

---

If super real-time performance is needed look at Kafka based solutions.

---

More Info:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-logstash-and-kibana-to-centralize-and-visualize-logs-on-ubuntu-14-04

https://engineering.linkedin.com/distributed-systems/log-what-every-software-engineer-should-know-about-real-time-datas-unifying

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase 2.0 (currently in Developer Preview, but soon to be Beta) offers a highly performant option for this. In the case of logging, you will need a very fast write speed, and the Views and View Querying will offer the flexibility for read/search/query. Couchbase 2.0 also will have full-text search via Elastic Search integration.

Check it out: [www.couchbase.com](http://www.couchbase.com/)